# onkeypress no detecta todos los caracteres

Tags: javascript

estoy trabajando con un formulario que al ingresar un texto a los inputs, este cambia el sentido de una oración utilizando otros sustantivos, adverbios y adj calificativos.

El problema que me ocurre es que cuando ingreso el texto al input y este se refleja en un span, no muestra la palabra completa, la cual esta ingresada en el formulio, esto solo ocurre si yo escribo la palabra y luego presiono enter, ahi me muestra en pantalla la palabra completa.

Por ejemplo si en el primer input, yo coloco HOLA en pantalla se vera HOL y si presiono enter, podré ver el hola completo..

como puedo solucionar este lag.

```
 <div class="container" style="width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2>FRASE: </h2>

    <p style="font-size:2em"> <span id="sustantivo">Juan</span> se <span id="verbo_sentia">sentía</span> <span
            id="calificativo_solo">
            solo</span>, <span id="verbo_volvia">
            volvía</span> a su departamento, y el
        <span id="cambia_silencio">silencio </span> era el <span id="calificativo_unico">único </span> que lo <span
            id="verbo_esperaba">esperaba</span>.
        Juan <span id="verbo_estaba_1">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_triste">triste</span> , Juan <span
            id="verbo_estaba_2">estaba</span> <span id="calificativo_solo2">solo</span> , muy <span
            id="calificativo_solo3">solo</span>. Y
        Juan <span id="verbo_tuvo">tuvo</span> una <span id="calificativo_brillante">brillante</span>
        idea:</p>

    <form id="frase" action="#" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Cambie su frase:</legend>
            <p>* Presione enter al completar cada campo</p>
            <!-- Cambia el sustantivo propio-->
            <label for="adjetivo">Cambia el Sustantivo propio:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_sustantivo" onkeydown=" return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo volvía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo(volvía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_volvia" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo sentía-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Sentía):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_sentia" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo esperaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Esperaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_esperaba" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba1" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo estaba 2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (juan estaba):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_estaba2" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el verbo tuvo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el verbo (Tuvo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_verbo_tuvo" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo2-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 2):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo2" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo solo3-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Solo 3):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_solo3" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo triste-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Triste):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_triste" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo brillante-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Brillante):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_brillante" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Cambia el adjetivo calificativo unico-->
            <label for="verbo">Cambia el adjetivo calificativo (Único):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ingresa_calificativo_unico" onkeydown="return FunctionCambiar()" size=50><br>
            <br>

            <!-- Eligue el sustantivo de silencio-->
            <label for="silencio">Seleccione un sustantivo para (silencio):</label><br>
            <select name="silencio" id="silencio">
                <option disabled selected value="value1">-- Seleccione una opción -- </option>
                <option value="value2">secreto</option>
                <option value="value3">reserva</option>
                <option value="value4">disimulo</option>
            </select>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>

</div>

<script>

    function FunctionCambiar() {

        document.getElementById("frase").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

        // cambia sustantivo propio
        var sustantivo = document.getElementById("ingresa_sustantivo").value;
        document.getElementById("sustantivo").textContent = sustantivo;
        document.getElementById("sustantivo").style.background = "#d1f0ff";


        // cambia verbo volvia
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_volvia").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_volvia").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo sentia
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_sentia").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_sentia").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo esperaba
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_esperaba").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_esperaba").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo estaba 1
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba1").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_1").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo estaba 2
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_estaba2").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_estaba_2").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia verbo tuvo
        var verbo = document.getElementById("ingresa_verbo_tuvo").value;
        document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").textContent = verbo;
        document.getElementById("verbo_tuvo").style.background = "#ebffdb";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo2
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo2").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo2").style.background = "#e9d4ff";

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos solo3
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_solo3").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_solo3").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos triste
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_triste").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_triste").style.background = "#e9d4ff";

        // cambia abjetivos calificativos brillante
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_brillante").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_brillante").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // cambia abjetivos calificativos único
        var calificativos = document.getElementById("ingresa_calificativo_unico").value;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").textContent = calificativos;
        document.getElementById("calificativo_unico").style.background = "#e9d4ff";


        // Selecciona un sustantivo



    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso se debe al evento `onkeydown`, este evento se dispara al presionar la tecla antes que el caracter se inserte. Si lo cambias por `onkeyup` funcionará bien.

```js
function leerInput(input){

   document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = input.value;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="leerInput(this)" placeholder="keydown"/>
<br><br>

<input type="text" onkeyup="leerInput(this)" placeholder="keyup"/>
<br>
<label id="label"></label>
```

Comment: Toda la razon amigo. muchas gracias..